# Is this an elegant solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

The problem is not complicated. Log randomly a name from an array of names.

My solution comes as this.

```
var names = [ 'nick', 'rock', 'danieel' ];
function randPicker(names) {
    var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    var name = randNum <= (names.length - 1) ? console.log(names[randNum]) : randPicker(arguments[0]); 
};
```

It seems to me that this code is not that beautiful, because im quite sure that there are better ways that perform much faster. Is that true?

Comment: The else part will not be executed until end of the world.

Comment: Just use `names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)]`.

Comment: Better use `console.log(names[Math.floor((Math.random() * names.length))]` without the check.

Comment: This is an appropriate question for Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is make the function return random element of the array and fix its getting:

```
function randPicker(a) {
  return a[Math.random() * a.length | 0];
}
```

And the test:

```
function randPicker(a) {
  return a[Math.random() * a.length | 0];
}

var names = ['nick', 'rock', 'danieel'];

for (var q=0; q<16; ++q) {
  console.log(randPicker(names));
}
```

Comment: It seems to me quite an intresting solution. But what about the vertical bar ' | ' ? Did you use it to return a default value?

Comment: @user2300068, no I use it for cast to int32 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get your randNum straight away to retrieve a name:

```
var names = [ 'nick', 'rock', 'danieel' ];
function randPicker(names) {
    var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * names.length));
    var name = console.log(names[randNum]); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var names = [ 'nick', 'rock', 'danieel' ];

function randomPicker(names) {
 return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * (names.length+1))];
}
```

**Explanation:**

`Math.random()` returns a number in range [0,1]
Multiply it by the length of `array + 1` to get numbers in range [0,length] with decimals.
Finally use `Math.floor` to round it to interger.

Comment: But `length` is not inside of the array, so you shouldn't add 1.

Comment: And 1 is not inclusive.